# Django исключение при авторизации

Tags: python, django, auth

Получаю исключение:

```
'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

в тот момент, когда проихсодит авторизация пользователя, который существует в БД, но **ПАРОЛЬ является неправильным**. При несуществующем пользователя такой проблемы нет.

Код:

```
def do_login(request):
    """
    Вьюха страницы авторизации
    :param request: запрос
    :return: рендер главной страницы при успешной авторизации / рендер логин страницы при неудаче
    """

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')

            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

            auth.login(request, user)

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        else:
            pass
    else:
        form = LoginForm()

    return render(request, 'cupper/login.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос полный текст ошибки.

Comment: Ну так вы же как минимум не проверяете, правильный пароль или нет. Почитайте документацию и примеры там https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#auth-web-requests